# creating and visualizing spacy spans

Tags: python, spacy

I have a problem visualizing manually created spans in spacy:

given the simple code:

```
from spacy.tokens import Span
text = "Welcome to the Bank of China. "
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
doc = nlp(text)

doc.spans["xx"] = [Span(doc, 0, 1, "ORG")]
doc.spans["sc"] = [
    Span(doc, 3, 6, "ORG"), 
    Span(doc, 5, 6, "GPE"),
    Span(doc, 2, 4, "welcome")
]
```

the following visualizer works:

```
displacy.render(doc, style="span")
```

[image]

but if the spans do not contain the key "SC" it does not work

[image]

The error is key error "sc"

What is the problem there? why is the rendering not showing me all the spans?
The code giving the error is:

```
doc.spans["xx"] = [
    Span(doc, 3, 6, "ORG"), 
    Span(doc, 5, 6, "GPE"),
    Span(doc, 2, 4, "welcome")
]
displacy.render(doc, style="span", options ={"spans_key":"xx"})
```

Comment: Please paste your code and error as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [in the displaCy documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/visualizers#span), by default the spans in the key `"sc"` are used. You can change it with the `spans_key` parameter.

`render` doesn't take `spans_key` correctly, you have to include it in options.

From the docs, modified to use `render` instead of `serve`:

```
doc.spans["custom"] = [Span(doc, 3, 6, "BANK")]
options = {"spans_key": "custom"}
displacy.render(doc, style="span", options=options)
```

Comment: displacy.render(doc, style="span", spans_key="xx")  does not work. That page of the documentation does not provide any example of using custom keys.

Comment: and display render does not look to have this possibility. displacy.render(
    docs: Union[Iterable[Union[spacy.tokens.doc.Doc, spacy.tokens.span.Span, dict]], spacy.tokens.doc.Doc, spacy.tokens.span.Span, dict],
    style: str = 'dep',
    page: bool = False,
    minify: bool = False,
    jupyter: Optional[bool] = None,
    options: Dict[str, Any] = {},
    manual: bool = False,
) -> str

Comment: If you look at the sidebar on the section I linked to there is an example - you have to include the span key in `options`. Don't paste code in comments, it's too hard to read - you can update your original question if you're having issues.